# How to set bunifu button as accept button?

Tags: c#, winforms, bunifu

I can't add bunifu button as a form's accept button. I am having this error. The property of the form does not have an accept button option. so I am trying to do it programmatically. Thanks!.

[image]

Comment: The `AcceptButton` property of the `Form` class is of type `System.Windows.Forms.Button`, but _your_ button is a `Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2`. So this could only work if `BunifuThinButton2` is derived from `Button` (I don't know if it does, don't know bunifu).

Comment: Well, the message says an explicit convertion is available, so maybe just cast it to Button: `this.AcceptButton = (Button)btnLogin;` or `= btnLogin as Button;`

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this type conversion by using the `as` keyword.
`this.AcceptButton = btnLogin as System.Windows.Forms.IButtonControl;`
Also you may simplify your code by skipping `this` keyword.